# Memory leak in unmanaged code?

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, unmanaged

I have traced a leak pretty far but I can't seem to understand (fix) it by myself. I used ANTS memory profiler first to make sure my code actually is stacking memory. It starts from using 25 MB but within an hour or so it is using over 100 MB. A friend of mine for whom I'm coding this for has actually been using this faulty program and he got it to spend his whole 18 GB of ram and got a out of memory exception.

The leaking part is not vital for the program, but it just is pretty much useless without the RefreshSessions() method.

I have been extending the project [Vista Core Audio API Master Volume Control](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18520/Vista-Core-Audio-API-Master-Volume-Control) from Code Project.

This is the part which seems to leak. Tested by not using it and then it doesn't leak.

Updated:

```
public void RefreshSessions()
    {
        Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(_AudioSessionManager.GetSessionEnumerator(out _SessionEnum));
        _Sessions.Refresh(_SessionEnum);
    }
```

(Removed the class code from here)

I have not been coding too much so I may have missed something, but if more details are needed you can actually download the source or I can just answer to my best ability.

(Removed unnecessary code here)

The leak was tested with this simple console app:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MMDeviceEnumerator DevEnum = new MMDeviceEnumerator();
            MMDevice device = DevEnum.GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(EDataFlow.eRender, ERole.eMultimedia);

            Console.ReadKey();
            int i = 0;
            while (i < 10000)
            {
                device.AudioSessionManager.RefreshSessions();
                i++;
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
   }
}
```

Update 2

I think I got it fixed. Have to run some longer tests, but at least it seems like the memory usage has stabilized. The idea came from dialer who found a fix for the leak in c++.

```
public void RefreshSessions()
        {
            _Sessions.Release(); //added this
            IAudioSessionEnumerator _SessionEnum;
            Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(_AudioSessionManager.GetSessionEnumerator(out _SessionEnum));
            _Sessions.Refresh(_SessionEnum);
        }
```

This is the part in `SessionCollection`:

```
public void Release()
        {
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(_AudioSessionEnumerator);
        }
```

This is not exactly the code dialer suggested (which I ended up using anyways), but still.
And as he said as well this might not be the best way to achieve this but I will go with it since it does not seem to have any adverse effects on my app.

Comment: I haven't seen the code of `SessionoCollection` class, but when you call `RefreshSessions` method, a new `SessionCollection` object is created, but the previous value of `_Sessions` may require some additional resources releasing/disposing code. You also create a session enumerator object, so make sure it's also disposed properly.

Comment: Unfortunately my computer broke down and have not been able to even try too much. As good your advice might have been from the description I gave, I could not fix the problem. I have been able to pinpoint it even more, but the origin is in the COM-part of the code. And I only learned about COM when trying to fix this so my skills on that area are weak.

Comment: Have you tried to build a minimal executable application containing this version of `RefreshSessions()` that demonstrates the leak using a loop with a few thousand iterations?

Comment: Did it now. Made a small console app that just creates the `MMDevice` waits for a key to be pressed (so I can see how much memory it uses) then calls the `RefreshSessions()` for a 1000 times and waits again. The memory consumption rises from 19 056K to 23 680K and holds. 10000 iterations rises it to 60 072K.

Comment: @Degath can you add the code for the application to the question?

Comment: It is now at the bottom. Hope it is what you wanted.

Comment: I found the leak by converting the program to unmanaged C++, step by step. The `IAudioSessionEnumerator` you retrieve by calling `IAudioSessionEnumerator->GetSessionEnumerator` is never being `Release()`d. Doing that manually fixed the leak. Right now I'm confused why the CLR garbage collector doesn't do that automatically. Maybe I should get some sleep.

Comment: Awesome! At least now I know what to start trying. Don't know how yet but will see. Thank you dialer!

Comment: @Degath See update in my answer, `Marshal.ReleaseComObject` can be used in C#...

Comment: Oh didn't notice your update at all. I got to the same result as you did and it most certainly does work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## ANOTHER EDIT

```
public void RefreshSessions()
{
    if (_SessionEnum != null)
    {
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(_SessionEnum);
    }
    Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(_AudioSessionManager.GetSessionEnumerator(out _SessionEnum));
}
```

Above code releases the SessionEnum explicitly and also fixed the leak in C#. **This should probably be taken care of in a better way though.**

**EDIT:**

The following C++ program is equivalent to what you did in the loop test program. The `Release` call at the end of the for loop fixes the leak. I need to go for today, maybe you can play around a bit and try to fix it yourself. Or maybe someone else can find out and explain why the CLR garbage collector does not call the `Release` automatically at some point in the C# program above.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <audiopolicy.h>
#include <mmdeviceapi.h>

#define SAFE_RELEASE(p) { if ( (p) ) { (p)->Release(); (p) = 0; } }
#define CHECK_HR(hr) if (FAILED(hr)) { goto done; }

const CLSID CLSID_MMDeviceEnumerator = __uuidof(MMDeviceEnumerator);
const IID IID_IMMDeviceEnumerator = __uuidof(IMMDeviceEnumerator);
const IID IID_IAudioSessionManager2 = __uuidof(IAudioSessionManager2);

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    HRESULT hr;

    CoInitialize(0);

    IMMDeviceEnumerator *deviceEnum = 0;
    CHECK_HR(hr = CoCreateInstance(
        CLSID_MMDeviceEnumerator, NULL,
        CLSCTX_ALL, IID_IMMDeviceEnumerator,
        (void**)&deviceEnum));;

    IMMDevice *endpoint = 0;
    CHECK_HR(deviceEnum->GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(eRender, eMultimedia, &endpoint));

    getchar();

    // lazy initialization as found in MMDevice.AudioSessionManager..get
    IAudioSessionManager2 *m = 0;
    CHECK_HR(endpoint->Activate(IID_IAudioSessionManager2, CLSCTX_ALL, 0, (void **)&m));

    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
    {
        IAudioSessionEnumerator *sessEnum = 0;
        m->GetSessionEnumerator(&sessEnum);
        sessEnum->Release(); // leak
    }

    getchar();

    printf("success");
    return 0;

done:
    printf("failure");
    return 1;
}
```

---

OLD

My **guess**:

`_AudioSessionManager.GetSessionEnumerator(out _SessionEnum)` yields an enumerator. When you call the constructor `SessionCollection(_SessionEnum)`, then `_SessionEnum` is being enumerated over. Each enumeration step retrieves an actual *unmanaged* object.

If it's a value type, then it would *actually* be copied into session collection (remember that the `List(IEnumerable e)` constructor *copies* each element). The copy would then be garbage collected, but the original object was allocated from unmanaged code and procudes a leak. If this is the case, you should free the memory immediately after calling the Collection constructor using some unmanage memory free function.

If it's a reference type, it wouldn't be freed either because the *actual* object in the memory isn't garbage collected, since it was allocated from within unmanaged code. If this is the case, you need to free the memory of the objects with unmanaged library functions when you no longer need them.

Comment: The leak happens at the Marshal part already, and commenting out the now different _Sessions update method does not effect the leak.

Comment: Seems like you were first! But I did not notice your latest update before I made my own solution. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Degath Just to clarify, this should *not* be necessary in the first place and maybe this "fix" has unforseen side effects. It could be a bug in the CLR or in the marshalling code of the codeproject library. Maybe you should ask another question on SO, why this particular COM object is not being released when its only reference `_SessionEnum` is being reassigned (maybe it has is a weird consequence of it being an `out` parameter, but I don't think so).

Answer (score 1):

If you have unmanaged code, when is the _Sessions memory released? If you simply reassign the private field, then the memory is never released.

Here's an example:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/clr/thread/b2162d42-0d7a-4513-b02c-afd6cdd854bd

You need to use the dll's method for freeing up the memory (delete[] in C++)

Answer (score 0):

.NET has always had the ability to easily leak memory - or rather, its doen to un-collected garbage that never gets cleaned up as the GC thinks they're in use. The most famous incident was the DARPA challenge team who believed the hype and thought the leak bug was in their C driver code, poor people.

Since those days, there have been quite a few memory leak profilers appear. I think the most famous one in [Redgate's ANTS](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/), but there are loads of others. run your app, see which objects out live their welcome, see which objects have a reference to them, put some code in unreferencing them at the right places (eg a few more Dispose and/or using statements).